# Group nested inner array in mongoose

Tags: angularjs, arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have mongoDb content as below:

```
[{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "57c6699711bd6a0976cabe8a"
},
"ID": "1111",
"FullName": "AAA",
"Category": [
    {
        "CategoryId": {
            "$oid": "57c66ebedcba0f63c1ceea51"
        },
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "57e38a8ad190ea1100649798"
        },
        "Value": [
            {
                "Name": ""
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "CategoryId": {
            "$oid": "57c3df061eb1e59d3959cc40"
        },
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "57e38a8ad190ea1100649797"
        },
        "Value": [
            [
                "111",
                "XXXX",
                "2005"
            ],
            [
                "1212",
                "YYYY",
                "2000"
            ],
            [
                "232323",
                "ZZZZZ",
                "1999"
            ]
        ]
    }
]
},{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "57c6699711bd6a0976cabe8a"
    },
    "ID": "1111",
    "FullName": "BBB",
    "Category": [
        {
            "CategoryId": {
                "$oid": "57c66ebedcba0f63c1ceea51"
            },
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "57e38a8ad190ea1100649798"
            },
            "Value": [
                {
                    "Name": ""
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "CategoryId": {
                "$oid": "57c3df061eb1e59d3959cc40"
            },
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "57e38a8ad190ea1100649797"
            },
            "Value": [
                [
                    "4444",
                    "XXXX",
                    "2005"
                ],
                [
                    "7777",
                    "GGGG",
                    "2000"
                ],
                [
                    "8888",
                    "ZZZZZ",
                    "1999"
                ]
            ]
        }
    ]
}]
```

Here i have an array named 'ResumeCategory' where it contains objects with different category id.

I need to
1. select category whose id is '57c3df061eb1e59d3959cc40'
2. The above selected category contains value as array
3. From the value array, I have to group element based on second value and need to get the user name list

Eg Output:

```
[{
    'CategoryName': 'XXXX',
    'Users': ['AAA', 'BBB']
},
{
    'CategoryName': 'YYYY',
    'Users': ['AAA']
},
{
    'CategoryName': 'ZZZZZ',
    'Users': ['AAA', 'BBB']
},
{
    'CategoryName': 'GGGG',
    'Users': ['BBB']
}]
```

I have tried to group using aggregate function as below:

```
resume.aggregate([
  {$match: {'Category.CategoryId': new ObjectId('57c3df191eb1e59d3959cc43')}},
  {$unwind: '$Category'},
  {$unwind: '$Category.Value'},
  {$match: {'Category.CategoryId': new ObjectId('57c3df191eb1e59d3959cc43')}},
  {$group: { _id: '$Category.Value', count: {$sum: 1}}},
  {$project: {'_id':0, TagValue: '$_id',count: '$count'}}
],function(err, resData){
        res.send(resData);
});
```

From above query, It is grouped based on Value array. It takes the array with three element to group. Can anyone help to group the value based on inner array value (single element ie. value[1]) and get the desired result.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$arrayElemAt` (introduced in version 3.2) in the project stage to select the second element in the array.

```
db.resume.aggregate([
                        {"$unwind":"$Category"}, 
                        {"$match":{"Category.CategoryId" :ObjectId("57c3df061eb1e59d3959cc40")}}, 
                        {"$unwind":"$Category.Value"}, 
                        {"$project":{"FullName":1, "secondVal" : {"$arrayElemAt": ["$Category.Value",1]} }}, 
                        {"$group":{"_id":"$secondVal", "Users":{"$addToSet":"$FullName"}}}, 
                        {"$project":{"CategoryName":"$_id", "_id": 0, "Users":1}}
                    ])
```

Sample Output:

```
{ "Users" : [ "AAA", "BBB" ], "CategoryName" : "XXXX" }
{ "Users" : [ "AAA" ], "CategoryName" : "YYYY" }
{ "Users" : [ "BBB" ], "CategoryName" : "GGGG" }
{ "Users" : [ "AAA", "BBB" ], "CategoryName" : "ZZZZZ" }
```

Comment: Hi.. I am getting error as 'invalid operator $arrayElemAt'. My MongoDb version - 3.0.12... Is this a version problem.. If so whats the equivalent of '$arrayElemAt' in 3.0.12 version

Comment: Operator $arrayElemAt' was introduced with version 3.2. So, it wont work on version 3.0.

Comment: Is there any equivalent for '$arrayElemAt' in 3.0.12 mongodb version???

Comment: I have upgraded my mongodb version and "$arrayElemAt" is working.. But it gets all the category but i need only category whose id matches '57c3df061eb1e59d3959cc40'.. How do i include condition for this inside "$project"

Comment: @user3211705: As shown in my answer, you can use the $match after the $unwind to limit to the categories with id 57c3df061eb1e59d3959cc40.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind)** `"Category.Value"` field twice since it has double nested arrays:

```
resume.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "Category.CategoryId": "57c3df061eb1e59d3959cc40" } },
    { "$unwind": "$Category" },
    { "$match": { "Category.CategoryId": "57c3df061eb1e59d3959cc40" } },    
    { "$unwind": "$Category.Value" },// <-- unwind twice
    { 
        "$unwind": {
            "path": "$Category.Value",
            "includeArrayIndex": "idx" 
        }
    },
    { "$match": { "idx": 1 } },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$Category.Value",
            "Users": { "$push": "$FullName" },
            "count": { "$sum": 1 }
        }
    },
    { "$project": { "_id": 0, "CategoryName": "$_id", "Users": 1, "count": 1 } } 
], function(err, resData){
    res.send(resData);
});
```

Comment: The example above grouped data using the first value in the array.. How should i use the second value to group??? ie. value[1]..

Comment: Which mongodb version are you using?

Comment: I have upgraded my mongoDb version from 3.0.12 to 3.2.10

Comment: You could try include an extra field with the `$unwind` operator that holds the array element index then filter the documents on that index, as in the update above.